# Authenticate MS-Sharepoint user using PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint, authentication

I was told in the 'case-of-monday' meeting that I am going to integrate MS-sharepoint authentication to a existing PHP site. The idea is a MS-sharepoint user can login via the PHP site which has permission to query a sub set of the Sharepoint resources (generic documents i.e. employee manual).

I need something to get started. Any idea what tool/library can get this done? or suggestions?

Thx in advance.

Des

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should think about writing a web service that uses the SharePoint API to query the items that you need, then provide that web service to authenticated users in PHP.

Comment: I came across simplesamlphp (http://simplesamlphp.org/) which could be a potential solution.